# How can i create auto suggestion search and page direction link information

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
public function searchlist(Request $request){
    $article = Article::latest('created_at')->paginate(5);
    $data['articles'] = $article;

    if($request->get('data')){
        $data = $request->get('data');
        $data = Article::select("title")->where('title','LIKE', "%{$data}%")->get();
        $output = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:block;width:100%; position:relative">';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $output .= '
        <li><a href=""  class="ml-2"  style="color:black;font-weight: bold;">' . $row->title . '</a></li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

Please tell me the how can add a page URL in the above code in a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to update  a href like this i have added url in href it may help you .

```
 $output .= '
    <li><a href="' . url("/folder_name/" . $row->id . "/pagename") . '"  class="ml-2"  style="color:black;font-weight: bold;">' . $row->title . '</a></li>';
```

i hope you got your solution .